# Cannot input text into textarea

Tags: imacros

Trying to input information into text-area for site 
https://www.gumtree.sg/post.html
only what is working is event recording mode, but when i reload page and truing to run code again I'm getting an error

> RuntimeError: Element HTML is not visible, line 2 (Error code: -921)

Code:

```
FRAME F=2
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML" BUTTON=0
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#rte" CHARS="Description Text"
```

Can some one help me to figure out how can i inptup text, as well trued with Javascript with innerHTML and innerText but seems not working as well.

Here how the structure looks like:
[image]

Comment: Can you actually see the text-area once you reload? I had to do several selections before a text-area even displayed on my screen.

Comment: @Matthew i updated with screenshot structure of the the input, but EVENT TYPE puts text not directly into textarea but into body id="rte". You can check the website i provided link, you need to select region and then it will display the details that you need fill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's acceptable for you, try to type the text via clipboard:

```
SET !CLIPBOARD "Description Text"
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#description-frame" BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#description-frame" CHAR="v" MODIFIERS="ctrl"
```

---

The following code seems to work (but not always):

```
FRAME F=2
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#rte" BUTTON=0
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#rte" CHARS="Description Text"
```

Comment: it gives me an error RuntimeError: Element BODY is not visible, line 9 (Error code: -921). It may work when you first use it, but when refresh page and try to run it again it will throw an error.

Comment: it stopping on this line : EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#rte" BUTTON=0

Comment: i figure out if you remove <p class="desc"></p>, but its not removing with JS it doesn't alert even innerHTML of tag: var x = window.document.getElementsByClassName('desc')[0].innerHTML;